# Replace or update object in array when property matches

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs to build a data filtering component. I am storing the selected filter options in an array that looks like this:

```
[{ "key": "payment", "name": "Payment", "options": [ "paid", "pending" ] }, { "key": "status", "name": "Order Status", "options": ["unfulfilled"] } ]
```

When a filter option is selected or deselected I want to update this array of objects. i.e If we remove the 'pending' option it would look like this:

```
{ "key": "payment", "name": "Payment", "options": [ "paid"]} ...
```

Is there a way in JS to push the updated options where the key matches, or do I need to remove the existing object and replace with the new one?

Comment: How are you updating the filter options? Are you using an `input` element? How are you allowing the user to de-select the filter option?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this one out, remove the object before adding the new updated object:

```
updateFilters(key, name, options) {
  this.selectedOptions = this.selectedOptions.filter(obj => {
    return obj.key != key;
  });

  this.selectedOptions.push({ key: key, name: name, options: options });
}
```